# 3 column grit with Text in the middle which grows to left column

Tags: html, css, sass, less

Can anybody help me to let the title grow over the left area?
But the columns should not replaced.
Only the title text should overlapse the left column

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  width-max: 1200px;
  height:436px;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 20% auto;
}

#areaA {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_1280.jpg");
  align-self: center;
  height:436px;
}

#areaB {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#areaC {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding-top: 48px;
  padding-bottom: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="areaA">A</div>
  <div id="areaB">This is a Title which should grow over areaA, but it doesn't</div>
  <div id="areaC">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

[Link to a CodePen](https://codepen.io/codegrabbler/pen/pojVExR%3E)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want your heading spanning over the first two columns, right? You defined three columns. After that, you can position your child elements with [grid-area](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area) like this:

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 20% auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 436px;
  max-width: 1200px; /* <- typo corrected here */
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ddd;
}


/* position and style title and areas */

.area {
  padding: 24px;
  color: #fff;
}

#areaA {
  background: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_1280.jpg");
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

#areaB {
  background: red;
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

#areaC {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 24px;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div class="area" id="areaA">Area A</div>
  <div class="area" id="areaB">Area B</div>
  <div class="area" id="areaC">Area C<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <h2 id="title">This is a Title which should grow over areaA, but it doesn't</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Syntax of the positioning is `grid-area: [row-start] / [col-start] / [row-end] / [col-end]`.